# Counting Rows Using a Loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, loops

I know how to count rows (and display the result in the form of a message form) using this syntax:

```
Sub CountRows1()
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (last_row)
End Sub
```

I was wondering if there's another way to do it without declaring variables and instead, by selecting a range and then using offset.

I was thinking something along the lines of the follow, but no idea where to go from here:

```
Sub UseLoop ()
    Range ("A1").Select 
    Do Until Active.Cell.Value = ""
        -- Something to do the counting, can't seem to get this part right 
        ActiveCell.Offset (1,0).Select 
    Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us more about "without declaring variables" and why that is to be avoided?

Comment: With your theory, what happens if there is a *blank cell* in the middle of your data?

Comment: It's not clear from your post exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Without variables - `MsgBox (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`?